# How to call a Dart function from Javascript?

Tags: dart, dart2js

I would like to call a Dart function from Javascript.

I would like to compile a Dart script containing a Dart function using `dart2js` (version 1.1.3) and then load the generated `.js` file into a Javascript environment and call that function from Javascript.

Something along the lines of calling `myHyperSuperMegaFunction` below from Javascript.

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;

int myHyperSuperMegaFunction(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

main() {
  js.context['myHyperSuperMegaFunction'] = new js.JsFunction.withThis(myHyperSuperMegaFunction);
}
```

I tried compiling the above with `dart2js` and loading the generated `.js` file into Chrome. Variable `myHyperSuperMegaFunction` is registered and defined as

```js
function () {
    return _call(f, captureThis, this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));
}
```

However, when I call `myHyperSuperMegaFunction(2,3)` from Chrome Javascript console I get the following error `NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'Symbol("call")' Receiver: Instance of '(){this.$initialize' Arguments: [Instance of 'Window', 2, 3]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a global (on the window) object in Dart lang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812372/how-do-i-create-a-global-on-the-window-object-in-dart-lang)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use `new js.JsFunction.withThis`. In your case just use :

```dart
js.context['myHyperSuperMegaFunction'] = myHyperSuperMegaFunction;
```

For your information `new js.JsFunction.withThis` has to be used when you need to use the `this` Js context. In your error, you can see that the first parameter is `Instance of 'Window'` which is the global context in Js.