# Exporting Dart APIs to JavaScript, without a Dart VM

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

I'd like to export a Dart API to JavaScript on browsers without a Dart VM. For example, given a class A:

```dart
class A {
  String name;

  A();

  A.withName(this.name);
}
```

I'd like to create a JavaScript object using the exported API with:

```js
var a = new A();
```

An answer to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321182/using-dart-classes-from-javascript) pointed me to js-interop.

However, I'm not able to get the expected result when working through the [README example](https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop#loading-the-generated-javascript). It appears that my Dart library isn't being exported into JavaScript.

**pubspec.yaml**:

```yaml
name: interop
description: >
  A library useful for applications or for sharing on pub.dartlang.org.
version: 0.0.1
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: any
dependencies:
  js:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop.git
transformers:
  - js
  - js/initializer
```

**example/main.dart**

library main:

```
import 'package:js/js.dart';

main() {
  initializeJavaScript();
}
```

**lib/a.dart**

```dart
library a;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@Export()
class A {
  String name;

  A();

  A.withName(this.name);
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="packages/js/interop.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="application/dart" src="build/example/main.dart"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

(It's not clear where the src attribute of that last script tag should point. I've tried using /example/main.dart as well, which doesn't change my result.)

I expected to be able to open a console after compiling (Tool -> Pub Build) and loading index.html, and then do this:

```js
var a = new dart.a.A();
```

However, I get this instead: "Cannot read property 'A' of undefined". In other words, `dart.a` is undefined.

The inclusion of raw Dart script in index.html suggests that js-interop is intended for a browser with a Dart VM. I tried running index.html on Dartium with the same result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The `src` attribute of the script tag still has to point to a file with a Dart script that contains a `main()` method. When the application is built to JavaScript using `pub build` Dart is compiled to JavaScript and can be run in browsers without a Dart VM.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Given that, any ideas as to where my setup is going wrong?

Comment: I didn't use this package yet but I know you need to run `pub build` to get JavaScript from Dart and the `main.dart` file the `src` file points to must not be in the `build` directory. When you run `pub build` the `build` directory is purged. The `main.dart` file should be in the `web` directory and the `src` attribute should just be `src="main.dart`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added a 'web' directory and moved index.html there. Edited src to point to "main.dart". I can "Run" index.html, and a server starts up. However, the problem remains. dart.a is undefined after loading the page. No errors appear on the page, and many dart files get loaded when I load the page, as evidenced from "Tool Output" within Dart Editor.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I was able to find a solution to the problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/27326963/54426

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does work on a JavaScript only browser. It turns out the documentation doesn't give all of the steps. Here's what worked for me, starting with a new project.

Create a new package project called 'jsout' using (File-> New Project/package). Delete these files:

- `test/all_test.dart`
- `example/jsout.dart`

Edit these files:

**pubspec.yaml**

```yaml
name: jsout
description: >
  A library useful for applications or for sharing on pub.dartlang.org.
version: 0.0.1
dev_dependencies:
  unittest: any
dependencies:
  js:
    git:
      url: git://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop.git
transformers:
  - js
  - js/initializer
```

**lib/main.dart**

```dart
part of main;

@Export()
class A {
  String name;

  A();

  A.withName(this.name);

  talk() {
    print(name);
  }
}
```

Create folder `web`, and add these files:

**web/main.dart**

```dart
library main;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

part '../lib/jsout.dart';

main() {
  initializeJavaScript();
}
```

**web/index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="main.dart_initialize.js"></script>
    <script src="main.dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

After updating these files, load index.html, and open a console:

```js
var a = new dart.main.A.withName('foo');

a.talk(); // returns 'foo'
```

This procedure worked as of revision [7afdb](https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop/commit/7afdb8dd896ab750eee43751cd44be2b18d496d4).

Comment: Why do you have `main.dart.js' as script source. You don't even have such a file. I think you should reference the `main.dart` file here. `pub build` or `pub serve` should replace this on the fly when loaded from a non-Dart capable browser.

Comment: That approach worked when running Dartium, but not Chrome. In the latter case, an error was thrown when the constructor was run. That error disappeared when using the javascript files.

Comment: When you load `index.html` from `build/web` generated by `pub build`? Can you post the error message? Did you try it with `pub serve` (or launch from DartEditor which used `pub serve` behind the curtains).

Comment: functionmain.dart_initialize.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function This error was received after command-R on the index.html file from Dart Editor. It started a server instance and Dartium. After trying in dartium, I loaded the same URL localhost:8081/index.html in Chrome, opened the console and attempted to instantiate dart.jsout.A.withName('foo').

Comment: I just saw that this line `part '../lib/jsout.dart';` is very wrong ;-) You must not go out of a top level folder like `web`, `bin`, `lib`, ... to import from another top level folder. You can only import files from within the current top level folder or from `lib` using the form `import 'package:jsout/jsout.dart';`

Comment: See also https://www.dartlang.org/polymer/app-directories.html (some things are Polymer only but most of it should apply to all Dart web apps).

Comment: I've fixed the part about '../lib/jsout.dart'. The error I reported in the last comment applies to that fixed version. Feel free to have a look at the repo on Github and suggest changes from there. https://github.com/rapodaca/jsout