# How to use Dart classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, dart2js, dart

I know a lot changed since [Using Dart classes from JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321182/using-dart-classes-from-javascript)

It is now possible to use dart classes inside Javascript?

I have some classes that call some APIs that I want to use in my Javascript app for the web.

Comment: Nothing has changed here - it is still not possible to call in to Dart code from JS at the top level without making functions available explicitly on the `window` or `context`

Comment: I found that `dartdevc` seems to output the code I want but the docs say I shouldn't use it. Even so, it complains about not knowing where `dart_sdk` is in `const dart_sdk = require('dart_sdk')`

Comment: You'd need to also include the dart_sdk.js file from the sdk to use DDC output. The specific copy depends on the options passed to DDC. Easiest way to use DDC is with build_runner and build_web_compilers. Note that DDC output is not guaranteed to be stable so we could change the calling conventions in a way that break calling in to it from js which is why we don't recommend it.

Comment: I've created a blank package using `stagehand package-simple` and I want to compile it to its JS counterpart. How does `webdev build` does it and I can't?

Comment: `webdev build` will effectively invoke `dart2js web/main.dart` (not _exactly_ but close enough for this discussion) - you can probably do that on your own. `webdev build --no-release` will do a lot of work that won't be easy to replicate. It will find the right `dart_sdk.js` file from the SDK, it will break your code and dependencies into modules and compile them all, and it will set up a bootstrap file that knows how to bring in those modules.

Comment: Long story short, there is no way of converting Dart to Javascript module and use that Javascript in an already existing app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21936509/374798 is still a supported route and works with dart2js. There is no _supported_ way to call into Dart from js as a full class etc. It's probably possible but it's not documented or guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: Ok. I will try that. thank you.