# How do I create a global (on the window) object in Dart lang?

Tags: dart, global-variables, dart-js-interop

Let's say I want to create a global object called `Hello` and add the function `world` on that object, so that any other JavaScript library in the browser can simply call it with `window.Hello.world();`

How do I create such an object in Dart lang and how do I expose it / place it globally / on the `window` object?

In plain JavaScript, I would be able to write:

```
window.Hello = {
  world: function() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
  }
}

window.Hello.world();
```

But how do you do this in Dart?

Answer (score 9):

I work on Dart-JS interop. Here is the cleanest way to do it using the new package:js/js.dart interop.

```
@JS()
library your_library;

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@anonymous
@JS()
class HelloObject {
  external factory HelloObject({Function world});
  external world();
}

@JS()
external set Hello(HelloObject v);
@JS()
external HelloObject get Hello;

main() {
  Hello = new HelloObject(world: allowInterop(() { print("Hello from dart"); }));

  // You can also call this object from Dart as an added bonus.
  // For example you could call this from Dart or Js.
  /// Hello.world();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how it will work with objects, but if you want to do that for methods, it's quite simple:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

main() {
  js.context['methodFromDart'] = doMyStuff;
}

void doMyStuff(String text) => print(text);
```

And then in you Javascript you are free to do:

```
methodFromDart("Hello world to Dart!");
```

You can try to find a way how to do similar things to objects.

Comment: I used this solution for debug purpose, and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late, but here we go. This is my flutter and dart version:

```
Flutter 3.16.3 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b0366e0a3f (3 months ago) • 2023-12-05 19:46:39 -0800
Engine • revision 54a7145303
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4
```

### Option 1

You can create the global variable in the index.html and access in the dart file

1. Initialize the global variable in the `web\index.html` file inside the script tag at the top:

```js
window.Hello = {
  world: function() {
    console.log("Hello World!");
  }
};
```

2. Create a function that call the method and set it the window global object:

```js
const callHello = () => {
  window.Hello.world();
}

window.callHello = callHello;
```

3. In your dart file, import "dart:js":

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
```

4. Call the global method:

```dart
js.context.callMethod(
  'callHello',
);
```

---

### Option 2

You can set and get values on demand like this:

1. Initialize the global variable in the `web\index.html` file inside the script tag at the top, but with a empty object:

```js
window.Hello = {};
```

2. Create a get and set function:

```js
const getHello = (key) => {
  return window.hello[key];
}

const setHello = (key, value) => {
  window.hello[key] = value;
}

window.getHello = getHello;
window.callHello = callHello;
```

3. In your dart file, import "dart:js":

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
```

4. Call the methods:

```dart
js.context.callMethod(
  'setHello',
  [
    "world", 
    (){
    // Do stuff here
    },
  ]
);

js.context.callMethod(
  'getHello',
  [
    "world",
  ]
);
```