# how to unwrap underlying event object from event listener argument in dart

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

i have following dart code:

```dart
@override
void attached() {
  document.onCopy.listen(_onCopyHandler);
}

void _onCopyHandler(Event event) {
  // Here i'd like to access event.clipboardData but it 
  // does not work for Firefox using Dart code so i need to
  // get access to underlying javascript event object
}
```

i've already tried following without any success on Firefox (for Chrome it worked):

```dart
var jsEvent = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(event);
```

as soon as i'll have a reference to JsObject i know how to call the method, i just need to get an access to that reference.

Comment: i've forgotten to mention that it does not work in Firefox due to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19368

Comment: Why did `JsObject.fromBrowserObject(event)` not work? Can you add the error message or some additional info to your question?

Comment: If `fromBrowserObject` doesn't work you could do the registering of the event handler in JavaScript already (and pass a JS method as handler) and then call Dart from this JS event handler method.

Comment: well, as soon as i did this:

    void _onCopyHandler(Event event) {
      var jsEvent = new JsObject.fromBrowserObject(event);
      // some code here
      event.preventDefault();
    }


i've got following error in Firebug's console (in chrome this exact code works without error):

    TypeError: J.getInterceptor$x(...).preventDefault$0 is not a function

and jsEvent['clipboardData'] is undefined so i am unable to access it in Firefox, in Chrome it works as well

Comment: anyway how can i call dart instance method from javascript? i know how to call javascript function from Dart but not in the opposite way

Comment: the Answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351766 shows an example. This could be useful too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664092, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669163

Comment: `fromBrowserObject()` should work for this scenario, can you file a bug with an example I can look at?

If that's failing, then another option is to write a JS function that gets the clipboard data and call that via js-interop. 19368 needs to get fixed though.

Comment: ok i filed a bug, could you please take a look? the example is attached: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=19816